# How to Loop Through Specific Column Names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

How can you iterate in a for loop with specific column names in R? This is the dataset I am using and below are the names of the columns I want to iterate. Also are the column number.

When I try to iterate, it does not compile. I need this to create a multiple cluster data visualization.

```
if (!require('Stat2Data')) install.packages('Stat2Data')
library(Stat2Data)
data("Hawks")
#summary(Hawks)

for (i in 10:13(Hawks)){
print(Hawks$ColumnName)
}
for (i in Hawks(c("Wing","Weight","Culmen","Hallux"))){
print(Hawks$ColumnName)
}
```

## EDIT

After what Martin told me, this error occurs:
*Error in [.data.frame`(Hawks, , i) : undefined columns selected*

This is the code I have:

```
if(!require('DescTools')) {
  install.packages('DescTools')
  library('DescTools')
}
Hawks$Wing[is.na(Hawks$Wing)] <- mean(Hawks$Wing, na.rm = TRUE)
Hawks$Weight[is.na(Hawks$Weight)] <- mean(Hawks$Weight, na.rm = TRUE)
Hawks$Culmen[is.na(Hawks$Culmen)] <- mean(Hawks$Culmen, na.rm = TRUE)
Hawks$Hallux[is.na(Hawks$Hallux)] <- mean(Hawks$Hallux, na.rm = TRUE)


# Parámetro Wing

n <- nrow(Hawks) # Number of rows
for (col_names in 10:13){
  x <- matrix(Hawks[, i],0.95*n)


  #x  <- rbind(x1,x2)
  plot (x)
  
  fit2       <- kmeans(x, 2)
  y_cluster2 <- fit2$cluster
      
  fit3       <- kmeans(x, 3)
  y_cluster3 <- fit3$cluster
  
  fit4       <- kmeans(x, 4)
  y_cluster4 <- fit4$cluster
}
```

Comment: Try: `for (col_name in c("Wing","Weight","Culmen","Hallux")) { print(Hawks[[col_name]]) }` or `for (i in 10:13){ print(Hawks[, i]) }`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried what you told me, but now I get the following error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(Hawks, ,i): undefined columns selected". Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Martin suggested two approaches and it seems you mixed them. If you are going to use the approach based on "col_names" then you should say Hawks[[col_name]] instead of Hawks[, i]. The first approach is using the name itself, the second is using the index.

Comment: Thank you, stomper and Martin! Now it works perfectly.